# In Blade Runner 2049 why did they leave Dr. Ana in the orphanage?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-runner-2049, blade-runner

I've just watched Blade Runner 2049 and I'm a little confused about Dr. Ana's birth and childhood. If Dr. Ana is the replicant messiah why did the "cult" leave her in an orphanage? Why didn't they raise her with love and safety?

And while we're at it what's the point of faking the birth of twins? Why didn't they just fake the girl baby's death?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Ana was born in 2021; the first replicant-born child. For replicants wanting to be acknowledged as people, not objects, this is a *huge* deal. However, this occurred during the time of the period where the Replicant Registration Database was still up and running, therefore making every Replicant a target (emphasis mine):

> **In 2022, in the midst of a human supremacy movement, Tyrell technician Ren Dus assisted a group of replicants in orchestrating the Blackout.** Dus did his part by redirecting a missile to detonate an EMP blast over Los Angeles, decimating all electronic data, **including the Replicant Registration database, which human supremacists had been using to hunt down and kill replicants.**

[Source](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Replicant_activism)

So having (effectively) a "Messiah" for the replicant people, during a time were replicants were being hunted and killed for wanting to be recognized as people, and where having the ability to give birth was the one thing that was denied *on purpose*, it's a huge deal. But since everyone is a target, and this child would *immediately* have a target on its back for just being born, you need to hide it.

As for why fake the twins, and not her death? As K discovered through the movie, these seeds were planted so that the people who knew what they were looking for, would be able to find it. Since she's the "Messiah", they would likely want to find her again.

So they set the breadcrumbs. Faking the twins raised a red flag. Faking a death wouldn't. Looking for an inconsistency was what triggered the discovery. "Stillborn" is nothing noticeable. This also allows for a misdirection as well, as K had the memory of the orphanage; therefore making him a target as well. So if someone *did* somehow stumble over the trail of breadcrumbs, they could be misdirected.

Comment: The ability to give birth is not being denied to the Replicants. It's a capability Wallace has been trying to develop, because reproduction will lead to an explosion of slave labor which he needs to increase his power, but he has been unsuccessful. Some of Tyrell's Replicants had this ability (at least 1: Rachael), but even that appears to have been either a fluke or a special feature. Wallace's overarching goal in _2049_ is to capture one of Tyrell's "breeding" Replicants so he can learn the secret and then put the feature in some of his own products.